# How can I change jQuery datepicker's width?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I got my datepicker to work exactly how I wanted it but now I want to make it fit my website better. To that effect it needs to be wider and preferably not higher, is there a way to do it without changing the CSS? Is it even reasonable to try to change the style sheets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the width of your datepicker by

```
  .ui-datepicker{
         width: [yourwidth];
  }
```

You can write your own css-file which overwrites the css you used, for example from theme roller, in places where you want a special css-styling for an element.

Comment: oh, thought it was gonna be more complicated than that. Thanks